# Excel - Evaluate cells based on a change in value of a cell in another column

Tags: excel

I'm looking for an effective way in Excel (preferably a formula/IF statement) to evaluate one columns' cell for every change in value of another columns' cell. See example attached. If column C is US or UK when column A is the same value then "Review" if not then "OK".

[image]

Comment: "when column A is the same value"? The same value of what cell?

Comment: Basically for every change in value of column A.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking.  You want to know if Cells in C are different with the same values in column A?  Or do you want to know when C changes and A did not?

Comment: Do you mean something VLOOKUP? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1